# Problema Sendkeys.Send({“ENTER”})

Tags: vb.net

Estoy distribuyendo un programa en vb.net que usa:

```
Sendkeys.Send({“Hola”}, true)
Sendkeys.Send({ENTER}, true)
```

Lo he escrito de memoria no se si hay algún error de sintaxis pero bueno la idea es esa...

El tema es que el programa le está funcionando bien a todos los usuarios menos a uno de Brasil.

Es el único usuario de esa zona que tengo y usa Windows 7, aparte de tener una conexión bastante lenta (tiene 270ms vs 30-80 ms que tenemos los demás de ping).
El problema que tiene es que se escribe el texto `Hola` pero no se envía, es decir que la tecla `Enter` no se está enviando...

Alguna idea?

Comment: Se escribe donde? y que tiene que ver el tiempo de lag de internet?

Comment: Se escribe en un textbox online, por ejemplo un chat o lanzador de comandos. 
Disculpa! Me he olvidado de comentarlo...
Por eso lo del ping..

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando el carácter antiguo de SendKeys

Sendkeys.Send({"Hola"},True)
Sendkeys.Send({~},True) ' Este es el Salto de Linea